# Convert angles between rotation-direction and zero-point

Tags: trigonometry

I got angles in mathematical sense. This means 0° is east and the rotation is anti-clockwise.

I need to convert them to 0° is north plus rotation clockwise.

The first one is an easy offset but how can I build up an algorythm taking into account to rotation direction?

Comment: I have thought about getting X/Y in a circle with radius=1. But I dont know which angle functions will then return in the correct new system when going back from X/Y to the angle.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle anticlockwise from east in degrees, then the angle clockwise from north is $90^\circ - \theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, maybe asking it helped me ;)

How does this look:

x = cos(mathAngle)
y = sin(mathAngle)

otherAngle = arctan(x / y)

The test values look nice to me. Switching x and y for arctan changes the rotation direction.